# Unitary and Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a Hermitian matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $E = E_n$ the identity matrix, how can I show that $(E-iA)^{-1}$ exists and $(E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1}$ is unitary?

That is $((E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1})^{-1} = ((E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1})^H$? I know Hermitian means that $A={\overline A}^T = A^H$.

Similarly, if I have a unitary matrix $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with $(B+E)^{-1}$ existing, how does it follow that $-i(B-E)(B+E)^{-1}$ is Hermitian?

Comment: It's analogous to the one dimensional case: assume $A\in\Bbb R$, then $\frac{1+iA}{1-iA}$ is on the unit circle.

Comment: A Hermitian matrix always has real eigenvalues.

Comment: @fiat_lux You did ask "how can I show $(E-iA)^{-1}$ exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real (prove it). Thus $A+iE$ is invertible, because $-i$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. But then
$$
E-iA=-i(A+iE)
$$
is invertible as well. Now compute
\begin{align}
\bigl((E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1}\bigr)\bigl((E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1}\bigr)^H
&=(E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1}\bigl((E-iA)^{-1}\bigr)^H(E+iA)^H \\[6px]
&=(E+iA)(E-iA)^{-1}(E+iA)^{-1}(E-iA) \\[4px]
&=(E+iA)\bigl((E+iA)(E-iA)\bigr)^{-1}(E-iA) \\[4px]
(\text{*})
&=(E+iA)\bigl((E-iA)(E+iA)\bigr)^{-1}(E-iA) \\[6px]
&=(E+iA)(E+iA)^{-1}(E-iA)^{-1}(E-iA) \\[6px]
&=E
\end{align}
The equality marked $(\text{*})$ is justified because
$$
(E+iA)(E-iA)=E+A^2=(E-iA)(E+iA)
$$

For the second case, you need to prove that
$$
\bigl(-i(B-E)(B+E)^{-1}\bigr)^H=-i(B-E)(B+E)^{-1}
$$
The left hand side can be rewritten as
$$
i(B^H+E)^{-1}(B^H-E)
$$
so you need to prove that
$$
i(B^H+E)^{-1}(B^H-E)=-i(B-E)(B+E)^{-1}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(B^H-E)(B+E)=-(B^H+E)(B-E)
$$
that only requires doing the operations on both sides. Justify each previous step.